# BigQuery, load dataframe containing repeated fields using python client

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I am loading a `pandas` dataframe from a python program into a bigquery table.

The code:

```py
table_id = 'project.dataset.table'
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
job.result()
```

My dataframe contains a couple of columns which store large arrays of floats.

There seems to be an issue loading repeated fields using the `load_table_from_dataframe` method in the python library due to some issues with the underlying `pyarrow` library, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8191).

What would be the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question with a workaround.

1. I first tried using `pandas_gbq.to_gbq()` however this has poor type support so does not work.
2. The working solution involved converting the dataframe into a dict and streaming this into bigquery

```py
df_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')

def insert_bq_row(rows):
    global client
    res = client.insert_rows(table, rows)
    assert res == []

insert_bq_row(df_dict)
```